# Installing virtualenvwrapper

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to install virtualenvwrapper and facing some problems..

Error:

```
error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper: Permission denied
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/build/virtualenvwrapper/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/x6/1rbbd59j1w7dx74lrrs181vh0000gn/T/pip-HQwbCQ-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /Users/build/virtualenvwrapper
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the sudo command to run your command?

http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/1.8.5/sudo.man.html